# How to check reentrant database queue?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, fmdb

I wonder if I can perform similar check in my methods to handle case of nested calls `inDatabase...` methods. `kDispatchQueueSpecificKey` is private and `_queue` too in `FMDatabaseQueue` class, so I cannot use `dispatch_get_specific` method

```
FMDatabaseQueue *currentSyncQueue = (__bridge id)dispatch_get_specific(kDispatchQueueSpecificKey);
assert(currentSyncQueue != self && "inDatabase: was called reentrantly on the same queue, which would lead to a deadlock");
```

Comment: you could try to get the current queue using `NSOperationQueue.currentQueue` and compare it to `currentSyncQueue`

Comment: @BoygeniusDexter I'm afraid I cannot because of FMDB implementation, because queue object of `dispatch_queue_t` type is private in `FMDatabaseQueue` so I cannot access it, I expect maybe FMDB developers could comment this case (issue https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/issues/796)